# Font face not working in IE 8-11

Tags: css, font-face

Code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'yanone_kaffeesatzregular';
src: url('../fonts/yanonekaffeesatz-regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/yanonekaffeesatz-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/yanonekaffeesatz-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/yanonekaffeesatz-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/yanonekaffeesatz-regular-webfont.svg#yanone_kaffeesatzregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

I have the eot#iefix and yet, font is not being displayed the way it should. It works fine in all other browsers. The font is applied on headings and the top right navigation.

[Project link](http://www.megaplaybus.co.uk/index.php)

The fonts are placed in the ftp correctly as well:

[image]

Comment: have you define the Font MIME TYPE ?

Comment: I can see the custom font appear in IE11. Try to clear your cache.